# How to detect when finger slides off the ImageButton?

Tags: android, touch, imagebutton

I have an Imagebutton and I setColorFilter on ActionDOWN, but if user Slide the finger off the ImageButton, it remains with setColorFilter applied.

**Question:**

- How to detect when finger slides off? Then I can apply setColorFilter(null);

  ImageButton i1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
           i1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

  ```
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              ImageButton button = (ImageButton)v;
              String principal = "principal";
              if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                  button.setColorFilter(0x8066bbdd);
                  return true;
              } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                  button.setColorFilter(null);
                  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SubView.class);
                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  i.putExtra("query", principal);
                  startActivity(i);
                  return true;
              }
              return false;
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean "slides off"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`

```
ImageButton i1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); i1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)v;
        String principal = "principal";
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            button.setColorFilter(0x8066bbdd);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            button.setColorFilter(null);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SubView.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra("query", principal);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
        {

            // Do some stuffs here
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE` Doesn't worked you can try `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`

Comment: I mean the user touch then slide the finger out of the ImageButton, MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE actually doens't work, I will try more funtions

Comment: The correct answer is MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, but you helped me also. thanks